# How to get counts for an xpath in a file containing multiple XML records

Tags: python, xml

I have a csv file that lists all the Xpaths that can exist in a document. When one is changed, we can update the status to show that.

What we need to do then is determine how many times that changed Xpath shows up in a data file with a non-empty value.  Now if the data file just contains a single XML record with the root IARequest the following code works fine:

```
filename = 'Schema_XPaths.csv'
fields = ['XPATH', 'STATUS']

doc = lxml.etree.parse('sample.dat')

with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, fieldnames=fields)
    for row in reader:
        if row['STATUS'] == 'changed':
            countlxml = doc.xpath('count(/' + row['XPATH'] + '[string-length() > 0])')
            print 'XPATH: ', row['XPATH'],'\n', 'xmlcount:', countlxml
```

The problem is that the sample data file contains multiple XML records. I can't parse the tree as the root node, IARequest, exists more than one time.

I can fudge it to work by adding a higher level tag around the entire file. For example, I change this:

```
<IARequest>
....
</IARequest>

to

<newRoot>           
    <IARequest>
    ....
    </IARequest>
    <IARequest>
    ....
    </IARequest>
</newRoot>
```

This again works but adds a manual step into the process and it doesn't scale well at all. I can get the counts for an XPath in a sample file containing 1000 records in 90 seconds but it takes hours if I try 10,000 records.

What I would like to do is to have a sample data file that contains 100,000+ XML records and I iterate through each XML record and then check to see if any of the XPaths listed in the csv that have a changed status are present and if so keep a rolling count.

I've tried  opening the sample file that contains the multiple XML records and for each record create the tree and then get the count for the Xpath but I keep getting errors.

The modified code and error is:

```
import csv
import lxml.etree

filename = 'Schema_XPaths.csv'
fields = ['XPATH', 'STATUS']
filepath = 'sample2.dat'

with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, fieldnames=fields)
    for row in reader:
        if row['STATUS'] == 'changed':
            countlxml = 0
            with open(filepath, 'r') as xmlrec:
                for rec in xmlrec:
                    doc =  lxml.etree.parse(rec)
                    countlpath = doc.xpath('count(/' + row['XPATH'] + '[string-length() > 0])')
                countlxml += countlpath
            print 'XPATH: ', row['XPATH'],'\n', 'xmlcount:', countlxml,'\n'


Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "test5.py", line 19, in <module>
  doc =  lxml.etree.parse(rec)
  File "src/lxml/etree.pyx", line 3444, in lxml.etree.parse (src/lxml/etree.c:83170)
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1834, in lxml.etree._parseDocument (src/lxml/etree.c:120742)
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1860, in lxml.etree._parseDocumentFromURL (src/lxml/etree.c:121089)
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1764, in lxml.etree._parseDocFromFile (src/lxml/etree.c:119997)
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1161, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseDocFromFile (src/lxml/etree.c:114546)
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 598, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc (src/lxml/etree.c:107723)
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 709, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult (src/lxml/etree.c:109432)
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 636, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError (src/lxml/etree.c:108243)
  IOError: Error reading file {then prints out the full XML record}
```

Comment: You need to clarify your question, *a lot*.  Forget the number of records or not scaling well or any of those implementation details.  As written, we cannot tell what you're actually trying to do at a functional level.  Try this:  "I wish to count all [ elements or attributes ] that have the property that __________".

Comment: I wish to count the number of times a specific XPath appears in a file. The file contains multiple XML records.  If I create a file that contains a single XML record I can accomplish what I need to do. 

I assume what I need to do is extract a single XML record from the larger file, parse it and get the counts for that XPath and then repeat for each XML record in the file. The problem is I continue to get IOErrors when I read each iterated XML record

Comment: XPath is a notation for the specification of parts of an XML document.  By saying that you want "to count the number of times a specific XPath appears in a file," you probably mean that you want to count that number of items selected by an XPath expression.  The answer is simply to use the `count()` function.  You say that's not working for you, but you neglect to explain how it's failing.  Usually, you would provide an error message, or you would provide the set of expected selected items and a different set of actual items.  I'm trying to help you formulate your question better.